# SMTP server on Server 2008 r2. Sorting Mail in Drop

Tags: smtp

I've managed to configure my smtp server to send mail using asp.net stuff.  This was my main objective and I got it to work.  Now I want to tackle incoming mail, because well, I have an smtp server so I might as well.

I currently have it configured to recieve mail in the drop folder.  ALL mail that gets sent to my @domain.com goes to this drop folder regardless of who the name@domain.com is.  So I just have this folder with a ton of emails to any possible user.  In the past, win2k days, I remember being able to add mail users and then subsequent folders within the drop folder.

Basically my question is: what is the standard way to sort the recieved mail by recipient?  I doubt the intended method is parsing .eml files, but maybe thats the new standard.  I really don't know and thats why I'm asking.

I not a sysadmin, I'm just mucking around on my own time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the POP end user functionality of SMTP Service was retired a long long time ago - so no more users. Now SMTPS is basically jsut an MTA with a drop / pickup directory, and if you need higher functions - get a full SMTP Server somewhere.

So, yes, it IS parsing EML files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there built in .net stuff that is designed for parsing .eml files?  I'm only going to have a few users, so the processing algorithm and stuff isn't that big of a deal.  I might even roll the .eml files in a db table.  We'll see.  At least I know what I'm up against now.

Comment: Follow up: Is there a way to setup outlook or any other email client to download emails from this drop directory that are only to a specific user?

Comment: Per definition not. SMTP is only for sending / receiving between servers. FOr outlook you would need another protocol (IMAP, POP etc.). SMTP service in windows is really for programmatic handling ONLY. CHeck out smartertools.com for a "higher up" email server.